# Can I integrate a Cloudflare Backend in my Wagtail CMS

Tags: python, backend, content-management-system, cloudflare, wagtail

I'm currently building a Wagtail CMS and i want to connect the database with my Cloudflare Database.

However, Im confused how to do that and I cant find anything concrete in the Docs as well.
All i find is AmazonAWS and ElasticSearch.

Am I missing something?

So far i wen through the docs and configured the Wagtailfrontend cache, which is needed to update my page when using Cloudflare

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve here? Do you intend to use Cloudflare as a cache, a database, a search engine, or something else?

Comment: I'm trying to use Cloudflare as a database

Comment: As far as I can see the only database product Cloudflare offers is https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-d1/, which is designed to be used with their Javascript-based Cloudflare Workers platform. I don't think there's any way to run Python-based applications such as Wagtail on that.